# Download Docusign Envelope with populated data

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to download an unsigned envelope form a template.

The URL I'm hitting is `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{our account id}/envelopes/{envolopID}/documents/{documentId}`. But this returns the empty template instead of the populated template. This seems to be the desired behavior but it looks like it is [solvable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153170/downloading-populated-pdf-after-generating-envelope). There isn't a clear explanation to how it was solved so I figured I'd ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using REST GET Documents to download docs from a DocuSign Envelope or Template? If from an envelope, you can enable the account setting in Features > Display SecureField initial value to all recipients. This will show the burned in initial values on the resulting PDF after the envelope is Sent. Downloading a Template's documents or a Draft (Created) Envelope's documents will not show these values. So if that is what you are trying to do, you'll want to get the tab values using the Get Tab Information for a Recipient call mentioned in the linked solution.